# How to stop video from playing in hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, video, show-hide, mov

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('verizon');">VERIZON<br>
<a href="javascript:unhide('sap');">SAP</a><br>

<div id="sap" class="hidden">
    <embed src="videos/sap.mov" height="270" width="480" scale="tofit"></embed>
</div>
<div id="verizon" class="hidden">
    <embed src="videos/verizon.mov" height="270" width="480" scale="tofit"></embed>
</div>
```

When I click on SAP the video plays. When I click on Verizon it also plays but the SAP video continues to play even though it is hidden.

I am very new to javascript.

Is there a better way to do this? How do I fix with the code I already have?

Comment: Make sure you mark the appropriate answer as such. It makes people more willing to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 var other = {"verizon":"sap","sap":"verizon"};
 if (item) {
    item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    var tar = document.getElementById(other[divID]);
    tar.className = 'hidden';
    tar.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].stopVideo();
 }
}
```

Other is just an object which provides easy access to the id of the video to be stopped. It uses the string from divID to obtain the other string.

Then once you have that other element, you traverse into its children to find the `embed` element. `[0]` is used to get the first matching element (your video). Then you can use javascript's `stopVideo()` method on it to stop the video.

Comment: Thanks Travis. I'm not sure that worked. I may have explained myself incorrectly. When I click SAP the video shows. If I click Verizon the audio from Verizon also starts to play. I can't see the Verizon video unless I click SAP again to "hide" it. Maybe this is a problem with the HTML instead? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2180362 - try hiding the other one when you show the current one, I showed the line in the edits: `tar.className = 'hidden';`

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution would be to set the HTML of that div to null rather than try to manipulate what's inside it to get it to shut up. After all it's hidden so why bother keeping it there.

```
document.getElementByID('div').innerHTML = "";
```

Thereby completely removing anything in there.

And to un-hide it (note you may have to fidget with this a bit to get the quotes to behave)

```
document.getElementByID('div').innerHTML = '<embed src="videos/sap.mov" height="270" width="480" scale="tofit"></embed>';
```

I think for flash or a heavy element like a video player this would be a better solution, imagine a page with 30 of these that are hidden, it would get pretty bogged down.